# Can't open modal box after closing it - Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a modal box in my view. On the first instance, when i click the button, it opens. When i close the modal box, it never opens again until i refresh the page. Why is that happening ?

**HTML**

```
 <div id="item" class="modal" data-backdrop="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title">Item</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body p-lg">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name of Product</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="productName" id="productName" placeholder="Product Name">
                      </div>                 
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="productSave" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '#add_prod_modal', function(e){
    $('#item').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: It's working fine for me, http://jsfiddle.net/0t73L56z/ . How do you "close" the modal?

Comment: I just click outside of the modal @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: It's working fine even after clicking outside of modal.

Comment: Try to recreate the issue, eg on a new page or in the snippet editor here - with no other includes/scripts other than required to show/hide the dialog.   You may have some other code that is destroying or overwriting the dialog.   See [mcve].